# Using a variable resistor with a DC motor

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc

As you may have guessed I am not particularly adept when it comes to electronics. This is something I want to change, so I thought I would make a simple circuit that controls the rotation of an electric motor. So I purchased a POT (B203) and some DC [motoros](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07VHB5WFC/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o09_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)(3v) and built the circuit. This circuit works perfectly fine when replacing the motor with an LED but when I place the motor in the circuit (replacing the LED) the motor does not work.

I am guessing the POT resistance is too high in the above case, at 20k. So I thought I would try some other values. I have tried a 1K and 5K (those burnt out straight away). So before I start purchasing more POTs I thought I would ask the people that know. How can I find out which POT I need? Apologies if this is a stupid question :(.

Comment: DC motors and LEDs have vastly different current draws which means a resistance that works for an LED will be far too high for a DC motor. Even ten ohms is probably too high, let alone kiloOhms.Sized at 10W, at least. This is also a bad way to do it. It is like adjusting the speed of your car by using the brakes...while always completely pressing down the gas.

Comment: For a simple transistor current amplifier with the understanding a motor draws ~10x current when starting thus torque is controlled by current and Voltage determines no load RPM. Thus mechanical load reduces RPM more when current is limited and thus change in RPM is greater. do NOT exceed the POT power rating P=V^2/R= I^2R thus if motor takes 1A start and say Pot supports 1/4W then with 250mW/2.5V= 100mA you need a current gain more than 10 when saturated. With a power rating > 3W to use 50% and rise tbd ‘C

Comment: Many years ago a HUGE pot controlled the speed of a DC electric motor. Today a pot can control a motor speed control CIRCUIT.

Comment: To make this work with a motor you will need to use a NPN Darlington transistor to "boost" the current your POT can drive. A TIP120 should work. Can you build very simple transistors circuits?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Sparky256 I can most certainly try. Could you link me to a diagram?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 you lost me

Comment: @Audioguru I am not sure what you are alluding to, sorry. I have said I am rather dim.

Comment: @DKNguyen could you maybe explain how I can workout what POT I need?

Comment: @DKNguyen you suggested this is not a great way to do this, can you elaborate and maybe describe a way you believe would be a 'good' way to do it?

Comment: You cannot do what you are attempting. A 3V motor speed control circuit is what you should be looking for, but NOT in a homemade looking site. Too many have errors.

Comment: https://www.robotroom.com/PWM5.html

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for the link and info. I will look into it ^_^ thank you again

Comment: @iNoob The better way takes a bit more circuitry which I won't explain all you need to know here. It involves switching a transistor on and off very quickly so that current to the motor is turned on and off very quickly So you need a MOSFET and a timer circuit that produces PWM pulses to switch the transistor with a duty cycle that can be adjusted with a potentiometer. It's like controlling your car speed by pulsing the gas pedal (or your oven thermostat which is turns full on and off but at different lengths of time). You may need to put a gate driver between MOSFET and PWM timer.